# asyncio automatic cancellation of subtasks

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

If an asyncio task *task_parent* creates subtasks *task_child* but *task_parent* is canceled due to an exception which is thrown after *task_child* was created, does *task_child* gets also automatically cancelled (if it's not protected with *asyncio.shield*)?

For example in the code below:

```py
async def f():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(coroutine1())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(coroutine2())
    r1, = await asyncio.gather(t1)
    r3 = await process_result(r1) # process_result throws an exception
    r2, = await asyncio.gather(t2)
    return await process_results(r2, r3)
```

if process_result(r1) throws an exception, does t2 get automatically cancelled (and subsequently garbage collected)?

And what if instead of using *asyncio.gather*, I await on a task directly:

```py
async def f():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(coroutine1())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(coroutine2())
    r1, = await t1
    r3 = await process_result(r1) # process_result throws an exception
    r2, = await t2
    return await process_results(r2, r3)
```

if process_result(r1) throws an exception, does t2 get automatically cancelled in this case too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find an answer to my own question. Task cancellation can be achieved via structured concurrency which in the current version of Python (Python 3.10) is not supported, though there has been a [proposal](https://github.com/python/exceptiongroups/issues/3#issuecomment-716203284) to introduce TaskGroups following [PEP 654](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0654).

Fortunately there is [AnyIO](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library which implements trio-like structured concurrency on top of asyncio. The example in my question can be rewritten in AnyIO to have cancellable tasks:

```py
import asyncio
from anyio import create_memory_object_stream, TASK_STATUS_IGNORED, create_task_group
from contextlib import AsyncExitStack

async def coroutine1(send_stream):
    async with send_stream:
        await send_stream.send(1)

async def coroutine2(send_stream):
    async with send_stream:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await send_stream.send(2)

async def process_result(receive_stream, send_stream):
    async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
        rs = await stack.enter_async_context(receive_stream)
        ss = await stack.enter_async_context(send_stream)
        res_rs = await rs.receive()
        raise Exception
        await ss.send(res_rs + 1)

async def process_results(receive_stream_2, receive_stream_3, *, task_status=TASK_STATUS_IGNORED):
    task_status.started()
    async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
        rs_2 = await stack.enter_async_context(receive_stream_2)
        rs_3 = await stack.enter_async_context(receive_stream_3)
        res_rs_2 = await rs_2.receive()
        res_rs_3 = await rs_3.receive()
        return res_rs_2 + res_rs_3
    

async def f():
    async with create_task_group() as tg:
        send_stream_1, receive_stream_1 = create_memory_object_stream(1)
        tg.start_soon(coroutine1, send_stream_1)
        send_stream_2, receive_stream_2 = create_memory_object_stream(1)
        tg.start_soon(coroutine2, send_stream_2)
        send_stream_3, receive_stream_3 = create_memory_object_stream(1)
        tg.start_soon(process_result, receive_stream_1, send_stream_3)
        # process_result will raise an Exception which will cancel all tasks in tg group
        result = await process_results(receive_stream_2, receive_stream_3)
        print(result)

asyncio.run(f())
```

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, the answer to all your questions is "No."

In asyncio there is no such concept as parent vs. child tasks, nor any sort of hierarchical relationship between tasks.  There is only one "level" - all tasks are equivalent.

To some extent, you can force a dependency by explicitly cancelling tasks in a finally block, e.g.,

```
async def f():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(coroutine1())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(coroutine2())
    try:
        r1 = await t1
        r3 = await process_result(r1) # process_result throws an exception
        r2 = await t2
        return await process_results(r2, r3)
    finally:
        t1.cancel()
        t2.cancel()
```

but this won't cancel any tasks that happened to be created by t1 and t2.  It only creates one level of dependency.

In a couple of recent small projects I have successfully used this class to organize tasks into hierarchies:

```
import asyncio
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class BagContextError(Exception):
    pass

class PBag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.futures = set()
        self.exceptions = []
        self.done = asyncio.Event()
        self.done.set()
        self._opened = False
        self._closed = False
        
    @property
    def is_open(self):
        return self._opened and not self._closed
    
    def __await__(self):
        yield from self.done.wait().__await__()
        
    async def __aenter__(self):
        if self._opened:
            raise BagContextError("Already open")
        self._opened = True
        return self
    
    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, _exc_value, _traceback):
        logger.debug("Bag exit %s %s %s", self.futures, self.exceptions,
                     exc_type, stack_info=True)
        self._closed = True
        await self.aclose()
        if self.exceptions:
            n = 1 if exc_type is None else 0
            for ex in self.exceptions[n:]:
                try:
                    raise ex
                except Exception:
                    logging.exception("Suppressed exception")
            if exc_type is None:
                raise self.exceptions[0]
    
    def until_done(self):
        return self.done.wait()
        
    def create_task(self, coro):
        if self._closed:
            raise BagContextError("Bag closed")
        t = asyncio.create_task(coro)
        self.add_future(t)
        return t
        
    def add_future(self, fut):
        if self._closed:
            raise BagContextError("Bag closed")
        self.futures.add(fut)
        fut.add_done_callback(self._future_done)
        self.done.clear()
        
    def close(self):
        for w in self.futures:
            w.cancel()
            
    async def aclose(self):
        self.close()
        await self.until_done()
        
    def _future_done(self, fut):
        try:
            self.futures.remove(fut)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        if not self.futures:
            self.done.set()
        try:
            fut.result()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
        except Exception as ex:
            self.exceptions.append(ex)
```

It's a context manager.  Inside its context, tasks are created by PBag.create_task instead of asyncio.create_task.  The object keeps track of its dependent tasks and closes them in the event of an exception, if the context is exited, or if the close() method is called.

If you use it to build an entire program, the tasks will be arranged hierarchically and the whole structure will be (somewhat) gracefully unwound when the outermost task is cancelled.  If you only use it in some places and not others (i.e., if you write asyncio.create_task in some places) this unwinding may not work very well.

I don't have a lot of experience with it so of course there may be undiscovered bugs. Here is a little demo program:

```
async def main():
    async def task1():
        print("Task1 started", time.ctime())
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("Task1 finished", time.ctime())
        
    async def task2():
        print("Task2 started", time.ctime())
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        raise Exception("Task 2 error")
    
    async def task3(bag):
        bag.create_task(task2())
        print("Task 3 done")
        
    try:
        async with PBag() as bag:
            bag.create_task(task1())
            bag.create_task(task3(bag))
            await bag.until_done()
            bag.create_task(task1())
            await bag
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        traceback.print_exc()
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    print("Bag closed", time.ctime())
    asyncio.create_task(task1())
    print("Program finished", time.ctime())
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks! Having a hierarchies of tasks is a bit too involved solution for my use case. In my use case I think I might go with something like context, similar to Context in Go, that contains information about active tasks and is propagated down the call chain to so that spawned tasks can add to it the subtasks their create and in case of an exception, the exception handler would access the context to cancel all running tasks.